# Data type required in a mysql for a date containing day-month-year

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

Hi guys I'm using wamp server and I have a database with a date of birth field. I would simply like to know what data type would be suitable for the way date of birth is specified on my website (January 01 1996). 
I would like to get a sample mysql query using the DATE_FORMAT() function. Most of the posts I've seen  use SELECT and SELECT*. But I believe this should be replaced with UPDATE. As in UPDATE users SET dob = DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m/%d/%Y')); .
Please find my code for how the date of birth is specified below:

```
<label id= "dob" for="dob">Date of birth:</label>
       <!-- Month dropdown -->
<select name="dob" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<!-- Day dropdown -->
<select name="dob" id="day" onchange="" size="1">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select id="birthyear" name="dob">
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
</select>

       </p>
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: "What data type would be suitable for...date of birth...?" Get this -  **DATE**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When saving date in the database, use the correct datatype `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Don't use `VARCHAR`

Pros:

- easy to manipulate
- requires no casting when manipulating data
- index will be used (*if a key was defined*)

Cons

- can't think of something..

If the reason why you want to save date in this format `January 01 1996` is because it is more readable than `1996-01-01`, then don't. This can be achieve using `DATE_FORMAT()` during the projection of the data.

Comment: I tried that, but remember with the date data type, it's displayed as 1996-01-01. isn't there any format I can use besides DATE?or maybe manipulate the DATE or DATETIME in any way to suit the format: January-01-1996. OR does it have to definitely be in the format specified by the DATE data type?

Comment: You can use a PHP DateTime object and its format function to render it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: if you have this format `January 01 1996` obviously it's *varchar*, then how can you manipulate it like getting between dates? In that case you need to convert it into real date which doesn't use any index and perform slow if you have large database. Remeber that database are storage and not for displaying of records `:)` *I hope you get the point now*.

Comment: Thanks guys, Thanx @JW. Noted, the DATE_FORMAT() will obviously work best for me. I did my research and found nothing on a function for formatting the date data type, so I don't understand why my question is being voted down. But it's all god. Thanks again

Comment: your question is good for me and this can help on future readers because the usual mistake for some sql developers is saving dates as string. `+1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, date_of_birth) ";
$query .= "VALUES ('John Doe', 'DATE: Manual Date', '2008-7-04')";
```

The manual date acts somewhat like most StringToTime functions in most scripting languages.

Another way to store time, and is actually a little bit more efficient, is to use the scripting language (like PHP) to format the time into microtome and store it in the database as an INT(11). So when retrieving the microtime back from the database you can just display it any way you like and is even faster to just do calculations with it :).

Comment: I'm still having problems formatting the date using DATE_FORMAT() in my query. All the posts I've seen use SELECT and SELECT*. But I believe this should be replaced with UPDATE. As in UPDATE `users`
SET `dob` = DATE_FORMAT(`dob`, '%m/%d/%Y'));