# Html5 type date - need full date value in database

Tags: sql, html, date

it is my html code

```
<div class="required" id="join_form">
                    <label for="DOB">DateOfBirth:</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required pattern="(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="age-format" max="2004-12-31" min="1940-12-31" />
                    <span id="age-format" class="help" align="center">Format: mm/dd/yyyy, mm-dd-yyyy, mm.dd.yyyy, mm dd yyyy</span>
            </div>
```

javascript to validate this type=date in other browsers

```
var mydate = document.getElementById('date'),
    mydateError = document.getElementById('age-format');

mydate.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (!mydate.value.match(/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/)) {
        mydateError.innerHTML = 'Please specify a valid date in the form 1940-2004 ';
        mydateError.style.display = 'inline-block;font-size:6pt;text-align:center;';
    } else {
        var value = new Date(date.value),
            min = new Date(date.min),
            max = new Date(date.max);
        if (value < min || value > max) {
            mydateError.innerHTML = 'Date has to be between ' + min.toDateString() + ' and ' + max.toDateString();
            mydateError.style.display = 'inline-block';
        } else {
            mydateError.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
});
```

php validation and insert for date

```
$DOB=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);

$sql="INSERT INTO register(DOB) VALUES("$DOB");
```

i want to get whole date of birth like  mm/dd/year but in my database i am only getting year like 1970 or 1987 like that....i cant figure out where i got wrong

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format

Comment: And in case you missed it in the linked question, you're wonderfully open to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse missed it what sorry ?

Comment: You need to be using parameterized queries - towards the end of the first answer, there's a whole section regarding security of SQL (and PHP in particular).  Essentially, trust **NOTHING** from the client (because not everybody can be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP mysql insert date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format)

This Link did help me I used this to validate and insert `type="date"` in database

```
$timestamp = strtotime($DOB);
$date = date('d-m-y', $timestamp);
 $sql="INSERT INTO register(DOB) VALUES(FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp))";
```

and my other Mistake was to set DOB as int  in database

[Data type required in a mysql for a date containing day-month-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176378/data-type-required-in-a-mysql-for-a-date-containing-day-month-year)

it should be `DATE` or `DATETYPE`

@Tonywilk Thankx :D